# Wordpress strange bugs on localhost [video]

Tags: php, html, wordpress, mamp, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WordPress quite a long time, but I can't get my head around the thing that happened today. I launched my WP-admin on localhost (using MAMP for OSX) and experienced a lot of bugs:

- Strangely behaving Advanced Custom Fields plugin - custom field headings formatted as normal text, no borders etc., infinite loading of a field, drag and drop not working
- Clicking on an arrow top open a dialog in menus in the appearance settings reloads whole page
- WordPress news in Dashboard not loading
- Not Homepage pages permalinks giving the 404 error

The strangest thing of all is, that this happens to all my localhost wordpress sites, not only this one. It was never happening before.

I tried deactivating and activating plugins, deleting and adding pages, restarting computer, updating MAMP - nothing works. Do you have any idea, what to do? I really need to get the wordpress working today. Thanks.

Here's a video of the behavior: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsVSc96vepw)

Comment: Did you try to change theme?

Comment: what's changed? you've changed a setting somewhere or some auto-update on your machine has broken your WP. Check your browser updates and also perhaps do a malware scan and a virus scan, just to tick them off. If it's all your sites on your localhost it's not site specific, and probably not plugin specific. Therefore it's more likely a systemwide setting.

Comment: try running the same jazz on another Browser see if the same effect occurs? It;s all about cutting down the options to nail what specific set of criteria cause these issues.

Comment: possibly try various tidying up issues such as repairing mysql tables wordpress uses, or flushing the browser cache, run a disk checker, that sort of thing to pick up secondary issues that *might* cause WP to throw a wobbly.

Comment: doesn't work.. chrome, safari, mozilla, opera... no change

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i finally managed to make it work.

1. In the wp-includes folder, there was a lot of files missing, so I added them
2. A few plugins were colliding with wordpress (f.e. ACF) - adding `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` immediately after the `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');` in the wp-config.php file solved it

I have no idea, why these files were missing - I didn't just remove them from all my WP sites on localhost. When I ran the antivirus, 8 issues were found. Maybe that was the cause.